# IE11 and Edge 18: why doesn't onload fire when combined with rel=prefetch?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, onload, prefetch

[Both IE11 and Edge 18 support prefetch](https://caniuse.com/#search=prefetch), but don't fire the `onload` event when the prefetched file is loaded.

If you [load this example](https://echodelta.co/pagespeed-tests/test-5-critical-css-and-prefetch.html) in IE11 or Edge 18, the file is loaded, but since the onload event never fires, the CSS file is not applied. If it were, there should be an orange hover color on the photo attribution links, and the background should change to dark green instead of dark blue.

While it's not working in IE11 or Edge 18, I can see it working in Edge 81, Firefox and Google Chrome. To test it, I recommend using incognito windows where possible.

My markup looks like this:

```html
<link rel="prefetch" href="css/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

In the Developer Tools, I can see that `style.css` *does* load, but it never fires an `onload` event, and thus never gets applied.

[image]

It could be that this is intentional on Microsoft's part, but I haven't found any evidence that it *shouldn't* fire the onload event.

Why doesn't the `onload` event fire when `rel` is set to prefetch in IE11 and Edge 18?

Comment: Are you talking about .train__attribution a:hover and color: #FF8C00? I tried to test your example in IE 11 and Edge 44 and Google Chrome browsers. I got similar results in all 3 browsers. Can you please provide more detailed information about this issue? It can help us to understand the issue properly. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question. When you say "similar results," what were those results, precisely?

Comment: I'm guessing your question is 'how do I get the `onload` event to fire when a prefetched file is loaded in IE11 and Edge 18'? Also, is there a specific reason you're trying to get it to load in old browsers?

Comment: No, the question is, "why doesn't the `onload` event fire when combined with prefetch?" The `onload` event should fire when the file is loaded. If I change the rel value to "stylesheet," it works. As for your other question, the age of the browser doesn't matter. Both browsers support prefetch, both support onload. But they're not working when combined. I posed this question to hope to understand or explain this aberrant behavior.

Comment: I would update the question to specify that -- currently you don't have any interrogative statement in the title or body so we're left to guess what it is you actually hope to get as a response.

Comment: I test the sample again and I can see the issue. Not sure why it is not working. I did not get any documentation that can confirm it or provide any information about it. I will try to do further research on this issue. Thanks for your understanding.